# Magento 2.1 REST API adding simple product with attribute set results in bad request reponse

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, rest-api, custom-attributes

I have configurable product added, sku KudosConfig. I have added an attributes called kudos_size and kudos_colour which have values of Small, Medium, Large and Green, Pink, Orange respectively.
The next step, I thought, was to add the 9 simple products with appropriate attribute value set for both kudos_size and kudos_colour. To do this I am using the following request:

```
   PUT https://example.com/rest/V1/products/KudosConfigGreenSmall
```

The body of the request is:

```
{
  "product":{
    "sku":"KudosConfigGreenSmall ",
    "name":"Kudos Configurable Green Small",
    "price":30.00,
    "status":0,
    "type_id":"simple",
    "attribute_set_id":4,
    "weight":1,
    "custom_attributes":[
      {
        "attribute_code":"kudos_colour",
        "value":"Green"
      },
      {
        "attribute_code":"kudos_size",
        "value":"Small"
      }
    ]
  }
```

This however returns a http 400 bad request response with message:

> Error occurred during "custom_attributes" processing. Attribute "kudos_colour" has invalid value. Invalid type for value: "Green". Expected Type: "int".

I don't understand why it is expecting an integer, all the values in the setup are strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand now. Instead of passing the actual value you need to pass in the value id which you can get from the catalogProductAttributeOptionManagementV1 service. Have tried this and now working.